# import dictionary from a module

Tags: python, dictionary, module

I have been struggling with importing a dictionary from a module I created. I have the module testmodule1.py where I defined the dictionary:

```
main = {}
main['run_length'] = 1
main['dtt'] = 30
main['nforcing'] = 12
```

Then on the main script then I import the module and I want to access the value using the key:

```
import testmodule1
print(testmodule1.main('dtt'))
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/Users/gerard/PycharmProjects/BOATSpy/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(testmodule1.main('dtt'))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `print(testmodule1.main['dtt'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the values of a dict from a key, you can either do `main['dtt']` (see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)) or `main.get('dtt')` (see [this part](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) of the doc) but not `main('dtt')` as like the error says, a dict is not callable.

Option 1:

> `d[key]`: Return the item of d with key key. Raises a `KeyError` if key is not in the map.

Option 2:

> `d.get(key[, default])`: Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else `default`. If `default` is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.